# Corresponding 'C' call for System.loadlibrary

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, static-libraries

I want to check if a library is present either in my app or the System. In java I usually do System.loadlibrary, but does anyone know a similar corresponding call in C ?

Comment: yes, [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) to open a library, and `dlsym` to get pointer to function from loaded library. Beware, some details may vary in this `glibc` documentation and actual android implementation. See ChrisStratton comment.

Comment: Yes, in general.  But beware that while that particular man page is good for understanding the general concept, Android's Bionic C library provides its own dynamic linker which is not going to exactly conform to the details of the glibc dynamic linker documented there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I was looking for something android docs for dlopen with no luck, so i decided to leave linux docs as most relevant. I will update the answer wit your warnings.

Comment: The documentation says dlopen("Filename", flag), what should the flag be ? 

Just to be sure, this is what it should look like right.

void * handle = dlopen(filename, flag);
if(handle !=null) {
  // Library is present
}
else {
  // Library is not present
}

Comment: @user2453055 The flag says whether addresses of functions in shared library will be populated when loaded `RTLD_NOW` or when you hit the function the first time `RTLD_LAZY`, never used other flags so read the docs for clarifications. The snipet looks ok